# what is $\int \frac{1}{\kappa}ds$ and geometrically which things it represents?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, surfaces

Let $\gamma(s)$ be a unit speed planar curve with $\kappa(s)$ as its curvature. Now what is $\int \frac{1}{\kappa}ds$ and geometrically which things it represents?

Comment: Is it the reciprocal of the radius of curvature or the signed curvature relative to an orientation? (Either way it can be zero, so that creates some problems. Also, your integral is not scale invariant in the way that $\int \kappa ds$ is.)

Comment: Yes it is reciprocal of curvature

Comment: That didn't answer my question. There's a notion of curvature where you just take the reciprocal of the radius of curvature and then there's a different notion which has a sign based on an orientation. Which is it here? (I suspect it is the latter.)